# Is there a premium plugin for appointment reservation?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, premium

This question will probably be closed. In the off chance that it isn't....

I am looking for a premium plug in that will allow the user to book appointments by reserving a block of time. There will be a public calendar that shows time already reserved.

There will be no financial transaction, which has caused me to rule out several options.

Comment: If you think a question will probably be closed off ... you should seriously consider whether or not it's constructive to ask in the first place. In general, we don't encourage "guessing game" questions (where you list features and ask for recommendations) so I'm closing this for now.

Comment: It's stupid. Even though there is a tag for "plugin recommendation" you close my question. Joel was right, this IS the summer of snark.

Comment: Here's similar question, why don't you go close that one as well? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18619/wordpress-plugin-for-scheduling-appointments.

Comment: Please actually read the description below for what "closed as not constructive" means.

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful to you having same features what you need http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/appointy-appointment-scheduler/

Comment: Just try this free plugin for satisfaction (Premium Version is also available): http://wordpress.org/plugins/appointment-calendar/